# "require is not defined" Using webpack 2

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I'm having problems with bundle my app using webpack, I've reading in the site similar problems though I've trying all the recommendations and I can't figure it out what's wrong.

Everything bundles well. However when I open the browser show me this error:
**Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined**

## webpack-dist.conf.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const conf = require('./gulp.conf');
const path = require('path');

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const FailPlugin = require('webpack-fail-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const pkg = require('../package.json');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loaders: [
          'json-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        enforce: 'pre'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
        loaders: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: 'css-loader?minimize!sass-loader!postcss-loader'
        })
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: [
          'ng-annotate-loader',
          'babel-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loaders: [
          'html-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    FailPlugin,
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: conf.path.src('index.html')
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      output: {comments: false},
      compress: {unused: true, dead_code: true, warnings: false} // eslint-disable-line camelcase
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('index-[contenthash].css'),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({name: 'vendor'}),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      options: {
        postcss: () => [autoprefixer]
      }
    })
  ],
  target: 'node',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  output: {
    path: path.join(process.cwd(), conf.paths.dist),
    filename: '[name]-[hash].js'
  },
  entry: {
    app: `./${conf.path.src('index')}`,
    vendor: Object.keys(pkg.dependencies)
  }
};
```

## package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
  "angular": "^1.6.2",
  "angular-ui-router": "1.0.0-beta.3",
  "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
  "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
  "debug": "^2.6.8",
  "express": "^4.15.3",
  "morgan": "^1.8.2",
  "pug": "^2.0.0-rc.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/angular": "^1.6.6",
  "@types/angular-mocks": "^1.5.9",
  "@types/angular-ui-router": "^1.1.36",
  "@types/jquery": "^2.0.40",
  "angular-mocks": "^1.6.2",
  "autoprefixer": "^6.7.3",
  "babel-core": "^6.23.1",
  "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
  "babel-loader": "^6.3.2",
  "babel-plugin-istanbul": "^4.0.0",
  "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
  "babel-preset-es2017": "^6.24.1",
  "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.6",
  "browser-sync": "^2.18.8",
  "browser-sync-spa": "^1.0.3",
  "css-loader": "^0.26.4",
  "del": "^2.2.2",
  "es6-shim": "^0.35.3",
  "eslint": "^3.15.0",
  "eslint-config-angular": "^0.5.0",
  "eslint-config-xo-space": "^0.15.0",
  "eslint-loader": "^1.6.1",
  "eslint-plugin-angular": "^1.6.1",
  "eslint-plugin-babel": "^4.0.1",
  "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-rc.3",
  "file-loader": "^0.11.1",
  "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
  "gulp": "gulpjs/gulp#4ed9a4a3275559c73a396eff7e1fde3824951ebb",
  "gulp-angular-filesort": "^1.1.1",
  "gulp-angular-templatecache": "^2.0.0",
  "gulp-filter": "^5.0.0",
  "gulp-htmlmin": "^3.0.0",
  "gulp-hub": "frankwallis/gulp-hub#d461b9c700df9010d0a8694e4af1fb96d9f38bf4",
  "gulp-insert": "^0.5.0",
  "gulp-ng-annotate": "^2.0.0",
  "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
  "gulp-util": "^3.0.8",
  "html-loader": "^0.4.4",
  "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
  "jasmine": "^2.5.3",
  "jquery": "^3.2.1",
  "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
  "karma": "^1.4.1",
  "karma-angular-filesort": "^1.0.2",
  "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
  "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
  "karma-junit-reporter": "^1.2.0",
  "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "^1.0.0",
  "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
  "karma-phantomjs-shim": "^1.4.0",
  "karma-webpack": "^2.0.2",
  "mdbootstrap": "^4.3.2",
  "ng-annotate-loader": "^0.2.0",
  "node-sass": "^4.5.0",
  "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.14",
  "postcss-loader": "^1.3.1",
  "sass-loader": "^6.0.1",
  "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
  "tether": "^1.4.0",
  "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
  "webpack": "^2.2.1",
  "webpack-fail-plugin": "^1.0.5",
  "webpack-node-externals": "^1.6.0"
},
"scripts": {
"start": "node app.js",
"build": "gulp",
"serve": "gulp serve",
"serve:dist": "gulp serve:dist",
"test": "gulp test",
"test:auto": "gulp test:auto"
},
"eslintConfig": {
"globals": {
  "expect": true
},
"root": true,
"env": {
  "browser": true,
  "jasmine": true
},
"parser": "babel-eslint",
"extends": [
  "xo-space/esnext"
  ]
}
}
```

I'll be thankful if anyone can help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hit this issue when building a backend using node + express and a hosted widget for use on the client side. My webpack config is divided into two, one for backend, one for frontend.

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

const config = {
  // set to false because __dirname resolving to / instead of absolute path when
  // built using webpack
  node: {
    __dirname: false
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['es2015']
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  // set to development to read .env.local variables
  mode: 'development'
};

const serverConfig = Object.assign({}, config, {
  // set target to node to fix build warnings
  target: 'node',
  name: 'server',
  entry: __dirname + '/src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname + '/dist'),
    filename: 'index.js'
  },
  // webpack-node-externals package used to exclude other packages like express
  // in the final bundle.js
  externals: [nodeExternals()]
});

// widget.js file served from dist/widget
const widgetConfig = Object.assign({}, config, {
  // set target to web for use in browsers
  target: 'web',
  name: 'widget',
  entry: __dirname + '/widget/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname + '/dist/widget/js'),
    filename: 'widget.js'
  }
});

module.exports = [widgetConfig, serverConfig];
```

Comment: You saved my day! Finally created a full functional server and client side rendered webpage with your hint.

Answer (score 19):

You're using an incorrect [target](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/target/):

```
target: 'node'
```

This means that the bundle is intended to be used in a Node.js (server-side) program, not a browser. You can change it to `web`, or just remove that line (because `web` is the default).

Comment: the problem persist

Comment: You should not use `webpack-node-externals` if it is targeted to browser. It is converting dependencies to a single require calls. Remove the next line after `target : 'node`

Comment: `target` should be set to `web` and `externals` should be left empty, unless you are using libraries that are not being bundles, like e.g. jQuery from CDN etc.

Comment: @StijndeWitt what if you are using libraries that are being bundled?

Comment: Fixed my problem! Thanks alot.

Answer (score 15):

Some of the configuration need to be changed:

`target: 'web', // which is by default
 // externals: [nodeExternals()], remove this as it is causing problem`

Comment: If you remove this then how would you add modules that you need??

Comment: Webpack will include the module code in your bundle. So just `require('some-lib')` like usual and you'll see the source code for `some-lib` being pulled out of *node_modules* and added to your *bundle.js*.