# Webpack 4 not excluding node_modules

Tags: javascript, webpack

My webpack doesn't exclude node_modules folder, i followed this link

[Webpack not excluding node_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33001237/webpack-not-excluding-node-modules)

I want to exclude node_modules folder from bundle, and have tried this older way to write: exclude: **path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')** but still node_modules is imported

But after this exclude, I have error in console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (out.fbd50140277b839fca03.js:1)
    at E (out.fbd50140277b839fca03.js:1)
    at t (out.fbd50140277b839fca03.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (out.fbd50140277b839fca03.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (out.fbd50140277b839fca03.js:1)
    at E (out.fbd50140277b839fca03.js:1)
    at t (out.fbd50140277b839fca03.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (out.fbd50140277b839fca03.js:1)
    at E (out.fbd50140277b839fca03.js:1)
    at out.fbd50140277b839fca03.js:1
```

And still node_modules folder is imported:

```
./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./css/style.scss 1.36 KiB {0} [built]
    [1] ./node_modules/css-loader/lib/url/escape.js 419 bytes {0} [built]
    [2] ./node_modules/css-loader/lib/css-base.js 2.33 KiB {0} [built]
    [3] ./images/furry.png 82 bytes {0} [built]
    [4] ./images/coin.png 82 bytes {0} [
```

**EDITED**

This is weird, I have simply webpack and still it adds me over 30 positions! Look picture below:

Webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './js/app.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'js'),
        filename: 'out.js',
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'js'),
        port: 3000,
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app.js'),
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: ['env'],
                },
                exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/')
            }

        ]
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: review your 'target' config  re: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44351310/require-is-not-defined-using-webpack-2

Comment: Still nothing... i edited to web, only when i remove line nodeExternals it is working but not removing node_modules

Comment: retry module.rules.exclude   using        exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),

Comment: Is the `node_modules` folder in the same folder as your Webpack config?

Comment: Yes, is in the same directory

Comment: @RobertRowntree i did that and same result

Comment: Uninstall `babel-preset-es2015` and install `babel-preset-env` instead. Replace `preset: ['es2015']` with `preset: ['env']`.

Comment: I have updated question, pls look

Comment: What are your `package.json` scripts and what command did you run to get that output? Also provide the contents of `app.js`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm currently reading a book and my config is set like this:

```
 module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            }
        }
    ]
},
```

The only place where I use the `path.resolve` is on the output key.

Hope this helps :)