# Why am I getting browser error: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

I am new to Webpack. My output file is getting bundled, however, the browser is giving me the error message:

"Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined"
'7310 external node-commonjs "url":1'

I am trying to import an npm module barchart-dot-com into my entry js file.
I've looked at similar questions on StackOverflow but they weren't too helpful.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Entry file ticker.js:

```
import "../styles/style.scss";
import stockmkt from "../assets/stockmkt.png";
import { financials } from "barchart-dot-com";

const tickerTab = document.querySelector("head > #title_logo");
```

package.json:

```
{


"name": "ticqer",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "home.js",
  "private": "true",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode production && node ./src/js/proxy/server.js && node ./src/js/home.js",
    "serve": "nodemon ./src/js/proxy/server.js && node ./src/js/home.js",
    "help": "webpack --help"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/chiahao-codes/fintech_app.git"
  },
  "author": "Chiahao Chou",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/chiahao-codes/fintech_app/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/chiahao-codes/fintech_app#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/preload-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.8.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.3",
    "jest": "^29.6.1",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.69.2",
    "sass-loader": "^13.3.2",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.3",
    "webpack": "^5.88.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "barchart-dot-com": "^1.0.7",
    "cnbc-market": "^3.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "node-polyfill-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0",
    "yahoo-finance2": "^2.8.1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "description": ""
}
```

webpack config:

```
    const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: {
    home: path.resolve("C:/Desktop/Ticqer", "src/js/home.js"),
    ticker: path.resolve("C:/Desktop/Ticqer", "src/js/ticker.js"),
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve("C:/Desktop/Ticqer", "dist"),
    assetModuleFilename: "[name][ext]",
    filename: "[name][contenthash].js",
    clean: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: "Ticqer",
      filename: "homepage.html",
      template: "src/home_template.html",
      chunks: ["home"],
      scriptLoading: "defer",
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: "Ticqer",
      filename: "ticker.html",
      template: "src/ticker_template.html",
      chunks: ["ticker"],
      scriptLoading: "defer",
    }),
  ],
  devtool: "source-map",

  target: "node",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|ico)$/i,
        type: "asset/resource",
      },
    ],
  },
  stats: {
    errorDetails: true,
  },

  externalsPresets: {
    node: true,
  },
 
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["require is not defined" Using webpack 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44351310/require-is-not-defined-using-webpack-2)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I tried changing/removing the target property in my webpack config file but I still get the same issue.